# Unsupported get request when requesting age restricted websites

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a list with FacebookIDs. The problem is, that for 20 of those Facebook pages I'm getting the error

> Unsupported get request.

I traced those facebook sites down

https://facebook.com/119348888090669
https://facebook.com/157092145950
https://facebook.com/433848736695233
https://facebook.com/105088476191522
https://facebook.com/214417591921032
https://facebook.com/196662581763
https://facebook.com/279207858845057
https://facebook.com/24643688653
https://facebook.com/131234540227504
https://facebook.com/140988045932863
https://facebook.com/112894312061915
https://facebook.com/371364406236904
https://facebook.com/194552773950177
https://facebook.com/213069036550
https://facebook.com/301712412500
https://facebook.com/229514460396870
https://facebook.com/293428175153
https://facebook.com/313832551463
https://facebook.com/118429398236170
https://facebook.com/211660322236154

And those are all sites of beverages, which are probably 18+. I'm using an App Access Token. When using a personal access token it works, but I want to use an app access token. How would I be able to achieve this via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App Access Token does not include information about any user, that´s why it will not work. You MUST use a User Token or a Page Token for restricted Pages.

More information about the different Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Seems like that's true. Sucks, 'cause I really like using App Access Token for it's easyness of handling access token expiration.

Comment: You can also generate an eternal page access token.

Comment: exactly, extended page tokens are valid forever. you can read about those in the links i posted.